# Windows 7 Boot to VHD using a VHD clone of the system drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, vhd

This seems like a not too difficult problem, and, after several hurdles, I'm maddeningly close. But I can't quite get there.

I'm running Windows 7 in development shop. I want to start using VS2010 to work on some stuff that won't be released for awhile.  My boss said no beta code on the production machine, but I could run VS2010 for this project IF I could do it in an isolated environment, like a virtual PC.

Well, I've used the beta and RC of Win7 on VPC's before, and it was painfully slow because of the VPC environment.  But everyone has been singing the praises of Windows 7's boot-to-VHD capability, where only the disk is virtualized, and you're actually running on the hardware.  Supposed to be little slower, but nowhere near the speed penalty of VPC.

I've spent a fair amount of time getting everything installed the way I want it. So I figured, I'll just clone my system drive using Disk2VHD, and boot off of that, and then install VS2010 onto that. (I keep most of my user data, including all my projects, in a separate partition, so that wouldn't have to be duplicated and would still be available.)

Well, I had some difficulties with that, owing mainly to the fact that I was using an old version of Disk2VHD - (get the latest if you're going to try it.) But I did finally get it to boot. (Scott Hanselman has a good blog post on boot to VHD).

But it wasn't exactly what I was expecting or hoping for. What I expected was that the VHD would become the C: drive, and the original (physical) C: drive would be either hidden or mounted under a different letter, and thus isolated and protected from any changes.

What you actually get is that the VHD becomes the D: drive AND you boot from the D: drive, BUT your original C: drive is still there. Which is sort of okay EXCEPT that the Registry on the VHD is a clone of the Registry on C: drive, and includes many hard-coded references to C:.  So the result is that some things come from (and modify) D: (the VHD), but some things come from (and modify) C:. (If you open a cmd prompt and do a SET to look at your environment variables, you will see a mixture of D:\ and  C:\ paths.)  So I don't really have an isolated environment. Most importantly, %ProgramFiles% is still set to C:\Program Files.

What I really need is a tool that can access the registry files on the mounted VHD AS FILES, not as registry entries, and do a global search and replace on all the C:\ in strings to D:.  I haven't found such a program. (I've tried to do it with a program called Registry Replace, but, even when running as Administrator, there are certain entries that the Registry won't let you change.)

Does anyone know of one?  Or any other solution to my problem (other than starting from scratch with a clean VHD and installing Win7 and all my programs on it.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not done any booting from VHD or this aformentioned fix

Refer to this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=223188) article. Be sure to change your actual system drive to something different. You may want to unassign that drive letter as well, for further isolation.

Comment: Thanks.  That article (about changing the names of the HKLM\MountedDevices subkeys) did the trick. I used Registry Replacer to Load the System registry of the VHD, made the changes there, and then when I booted to the VHD, it was my new C: drive, which was what I wanted.

Comment: Glad that worked, and nice to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I guess if we clean the registry key before capture the VHD, It may not need to change the HKLM\MountedDevices subkeys. Not tested yet;)