# Install an OS on an external USB 2.0 hard disk - how about the performance?

Tags: usb, operating-systems

I want to use multiple OS (not at the same time) and I don't want to install all OS in one HDD. So I want to use an external USB 2.0 box (my Dell T3500 only supports USB 2.0) and several HDDs. Each OS for one HDD. When I want to switch OS, I can just shutdown the current OS, replace the HDD, then boot it.

My concern is about performance. Will it have significantly performance downgrade? Thanks.

P.S.: I also tried a 3.5" SATA HDD box but the CD/DVD bracket is 2~3mm smaller than the 3.5" SATA HDD box so I can't install the HDD Box in it. :(

Answer (score 4):

It will be deadly slow, IF you can get your OS to install on USB. It is generally not recommended, because of the speed.

If you are using Windows 7 or later, I would recommend making use of [VHD](https://superuser.com/questions/72808/windows-7-boot-to-vhd-using-a-vhd-clone-of-the-system-drive)s for installing your Operating Systems. If you are using older versions of Windows, or using Linux, I would check out virtulization programs, such as [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html) Workstation or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (free)

Another issue, depending on your operating system, is whether or not it will load USB before the boot loader, which *should* be on an internal hard drive. Finally, does your BIOS support booting from a USB hard drive?

Comment: Thank you, Luke. I have confirmed BIOS supports booting from a USB hard drive. For the virtualization solution, sorry, I had to use a software which can't be installed in an virtualized OS. I didn't tried the VHD solution but I guess it's like running a guest os on top of Windows. So it's not applicable for my case. :( Anyway, thanks for your suggestion! ;)

Comment: @landy You can boot a vhd on your system without starting windows. It's a method that helps testers keep their systems the same. to delete an os, delete its vhd file and it's gone

Answer (score 2):

I did it with SLAX on a Dell C521 AMD X2 a few years ago. Was going to make this the box's configuration with a thumb drive hooked up to internal USB jumpers. It actually worked quite well. IMHO, your performance will depend on the quality of the USB stick. I have a couple USB thumb drives I boot Ubuntu Live OS from and performance is acceptably fast, nothing as miserable as trying to run from a live-CD.

Comment: Assuming you have a good USB flash drive, yes, this method is great. I believe the OP is asking about hard drives though. I did upvote nonetheless, as USB flash drives are great for troubleshooting compared to CDs

Comment: Ha! Didn't even notice. Anecdotally, a HDD I removed from a laptop when I installed linux got put into an external case and then inadvertently left plugged in. I was more than disturbed when that laptop rebooted to XP. I noticed no difference in performance (while shutting down).

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks for your suggestion. As Luke said, I need to install OS on hard drives. It's a good news that you didn't notice difference in performance.